# Within JIRA, how can I detail project deviations with a wiki style field after creation

Tags: jira

We are starting out on detailing project deviations, and have found a combination of a JIRA ticket to show its progress/stage/state (Todo/Scoping/UX/etc), and Confluence Page to detail the requirements/deviations/etc (User Story, Requirements, UX, screenshots, etc).

I find the separation of the two concerning, as the ticket is really just a marker with no details in, and the wiki page contains has no state/progress, as well as detailing changes of a product in a wiki as that gets out of date quickly.

Q: Can I create a field, that is editable like the comments field is, but named "Requirements" or the like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I will begin the discussion.

Are you mainly asking if it is possible to create a custom field? That is a feature of Jira, more info here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field

In short, yes, you could have a custom field that resembles the Comments section but call it Requirements, and use Attachments for your screenshots, etc. Your bug/task/etc pages would be pretty long though depending on how detailed your requirements are.

Alternatively, you could connect Confluence pages and Jira tasks. More info is here: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/02/link-jira-issues-to-confluence-pages-automatically/